Terraform create ECR repo if not exist
I'm using the below code in order to create ECR repo, yet, I fail to change it "conditionally create" ..
resource "aws_ecr_repository" "ecr_repository" {
  for_each = local.repositories
  name     = each.key


  image_scanning_configuration {
      scan_on_push = true
  }

  tags = var.tags
}

resource "aws_ecr_lifecycle_policy" "default_policy" {
  for_each   = local.repositories
  repository = aws_ecr_repository.ecr_repository[each.key].name

  policy = jsonencode({rules = concat(local.untagged_images_rule, local.pull_request_images_rule, local.remove_max_images_rule)})

  depends_on = [
    aws_ecr_repository.ecr_repository
  ]
}

Adding   count        = data.external.check_repo.result.success == "true" ? 0 : 1 fails as well ...
Is there a way to have "loop" resource which "call" the "aws_ecr_repository" ?
Any other way ?

Creating the ECR repo if it does not exist is the default behavior of Terraform.

@MatthewSchuchard - It will fail if repo already exist correct ? I want to avoid this

If the resource exists but was not managed/created with Terraform you can import it into the state file.

I would not advice to work like this. As mentioned in the comments, import the existing ECRs, so that they are managed in the terraform state as well. There is however a (really ugly) way to check for an existing ECR with a data block. You need to do some manipulation of the output with jq, since it needs to be valid json.
locals {
  repositories = [
    "repo1",
    "repo2",
    "repo3"
  ]
}

# Use the AWS cli inside this data resource
# JSON output is stored in the result attribute
data "external" "ecr" {
  for_each = toset(local.repositories)
  
  program = [
    "sh",
    "-c",
    "aws ecr describe-repositories | jq -r 'any(.repositories[]; .repositoryName == \"each.key\") | {exists:.}'"
  ]
}

# Check if the exist fields equals true in the result attribute
# Note that the boolean is actually a string
resource "aws_ecr_repository" "ecr" {
  for_each = {
    ecr in toset(local.repositories) :
    if data.external.ecr[${ecr}].result["exists"] == "true"
  }
    
  name = each.key
  tags = var.tags
}

